# Two variables from if else statement to ternary operator

Tags: shortcut

> In JAVA, what is the best way to convert the below code to use ternary operator:

```
if (input > 0) 
{
    result1 = input;
    result2 = input;
} 
else 
{
    result1 = -1;
    result2 = -1;
}
```

Comment: Please at least mention what language you're programming in.

Comment: input > 0 ? ( result1 = result2 = input ): ( result1 = result2 = -1)

Comment: @madhusudhan thank you, someone also answered a shorter form in post below...

Comment: @Jol please consider updating your question with some more detail about language etc so that the question and answer become more useful and valuable for others :)

Comment: @molbdnilo It is java language.

Comment: @Gorp Ok. It is java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short and Simple:**

```
result1 = result2 = input > 0 ? input : -1;
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you!